# In Luke 13:28 does Jesus mean Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob are prophets?

Tags: luke

As Jesus is traveling through towns and villages on His way to Jerusalem, someone asks Him about the number of those who will be saved:

> And someone said to him, “Lord, will those who are saved be few?” (Luke 13:23 ) [ESV]

Jesus gives this answer:

> <sup>24</sup> “Strive to enter through the narrow door. For many, I tell you, will seek to enter and will not be able. <sup>25</sup> When once the master of the house has risen and shut the door, and you begin to stand outside and to knock at the door, saying, ‘Lord, open to us,’ then he will answer you, ‘I do not know where you come from.’ <sup>26</sup> Then you will begin to say, ‘We ate and drank in your presence, and you taught in our streets.’ <sup>27</sup> But he will say, ‘I tell you, I do not know where you come from. Depart from me, all you workers of evil!’ <sup>28</sup> In that place there will be weeping and gnashing of teeth, **when you see Abraham and Isaac and Jacob and all the prophets in the kingdom of God** but you yourselves cast out. <sup>29</sup> And people will come from east and west, and from north and south, and recline at table in the kingdom of God. <sup>30</sup> And behold, some are last who will be first, and some are first who will be last.”(Luke 13)

Is Jesus calling Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob prophets?

Comment: Abraham is already a prophet in Genesis (20:7)

Comment: The [historical books](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_books) are part of the [prophets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nevi'im). Without denying that the two terms (i.e., *prophet* and *seer*) are indeed connected (1 Samuel 9:9), the former is not reduced to the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In Luke 13:28 does Jesus mean Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob are prophets?**

The answer is **Yes.**

Psalm 105:9-15 also  classifies them as prophets
.
Psalm 105:9-15 NASB

> 9 The covenant which He made with **Abraham**,  And His oath to **Isaac**. 10
> Then He confirmed it to **Jacob** for a statute, To Israel as an
> everlasting covenant, 11 Saying, “To you I will give the land of
> Canaan As the portion of your inheritance,”  12 When they were only a
> few men in number,  Very few, and strangers in it.  13 And they
> wandered about from nation to nation,  From one kingdom to another
> people.  14 He permitted no man to oppress them,  and He reproved
> kings for their sakes:  15 **“Do not touch My anointed ones,  And do
> My prophets no harm.”**

Comment: Wow.  +1 for the psalm passage

Answer (score 1):

> Is Jesus calling Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob prophets?

It's a list if significant people from the past who were well known Godly people. Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob are the patriarchs of Israel. We see these three referred to as part of a list in other places, Exodus 3:16, and Exodus 33:1 as two examples. Rather than list all of the prophets Jesus refers to them as a group. It is a list of people who have entered through "the narrow door".

This passage does not indicate that Jesus was including Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob as part of the group of prophets.

Answer (score 1):

Jesus' words do not demand that we conclude (at least in this instance) that Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob are prophets, inasmuch as it is synonymous with "the fathers and the prophets" (or "the patriarchs and prophets"). To further muddy an answer with Scriptural references betrays the simplicity of the matter.